# plotly vs ggplot - multiple lines bug

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am plotting my data using plot_ly and for some unknown reason it shows "doubling" lines connecting dots which should not be connected! i am getting a very different plot using ggplot... How to fix this with plotly?

My code:

```
test%>%ggplot(aes(
    year, value
   ))+geom_line()

plot_ly(test, x = ~year, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
```

What I see:

plotly

[image]

ggplot

[image]

Comment: A guess: I wonder if plotly is treating it like geom_path, with data plotted in order of appearance instead of order of x axis. If so, could be fixed by arranging in order of X values in the step before plotting.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this given the current information. If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).